# How to alter the properties of the Primary Key in a column

Tags: mysql

Im trying to alter a table named Artist(id,name), with id as its Primary Key, so as to match with another table Song(title, artist_id, year). The column artist_id is a Foreign Key.
The column artist_id was NOT set to be null when deleted, so i altered it using this query:

ALTER TABLE Song ADD CONSTRAINT FK_song_4 FOREIGN KEY (artist_id) REFERENCES Artist(id)  ON DELETE SET NULL;

I am trying to implement the same alteration on Artist as well (to set its Primary Key null on delete, so as to be able to insert more values to one of those tables, but the exact same syntax is not correct in order to alter the Primary Key) but MySQL Workbench points out a syntax error.

Summing up, my problem is:
how to set a Primary Key null on delete

Here is my code:

```
alter table Song add constraint FK_tragoudi_3 foreign key (artist_id) references Artist(id)  ON DELETE set null ;

alter table Artist add constraint PK_artist_1 primary key (id) on delete set null;

SET @titl="Beat it";
SET @composer ="122";
SET @year= 1990;
SET @song_writ="211";

insert into Song (title, composer, year, song_writer) values (@titl, @compose, @yearr, @song_writ);
insert into Artist (id, name, surname, year) values (@composer, "George", "Smith", 1960);
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show exactly what syntax error your client returns?

Comment: A primary key can't be set null - it's not totally obvious to me what action you're trying to complete. A deletion in `Artist` is just a deletion, and the FK you defined on `Song` will receive cascading nulls when you delete from `Artist`.

Comment: Error Code: 1005. Cant create table 
23:20:46 alter table Song add constraint FK_song_3 foreign key (artist_id) references Artist(id)  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `ask2db`.`#sql-1370_9` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") 0.109 sec

Comment: Ok, but please then post the exact, complete `CREATE TABLE` statement you are trying to use.

Comment: i posted it on the description above!

Comment: It makes no sense to use "on delete xxx" on a primary key, it is a property of foreign keys. I'm not sure you know what "on delete set null" means. It means: if you delete the row artist.id in table artist, it will set the value of every song.artist_id in table song that has this artist.id to null (so the reference given by the foreign key song.artist_id -> artist.id will still be intact!), otherwise you have to manually update all the songs that are referrering to artist.id to be able to delete that row in table artist. Maybe explain again your intention (it's unclear to me) to get a tip.

Comment: In order not to have your headache, i would redesign the DB with tables: persons(person_id PK, name, ..), songs(song_id PK, title, ..), songs_singers(song_id FK, person_id FK), songs_composers(song_id FK, person_id FK), songs_writers(song_id FK, person_id FK).